# template not displaying binded data after routed, on first click - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, route-provider, ngroute, angular-template

Trying to route to different view template from the index page. Initially, the list on main index page gets loaded and the ***main.html*** gets loaded in ng-view, displaying it's text contents. The data from 'MainCtrl' is broadcasted properly and works fine. Now, the confusion is, when the item from the list is clicked, it gets routed to content template(***content.html***), but the content does not display the binded value on the first click on the list. But, after second click, it starts showing the binded values that is broadcasted from ***MainCtrl***.

```
<body ng-app="myApp">

  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
     <ul ng-repeat="value in msg" ng-click="setSelectedValue(value)">
         <li>
           <a href='#/content'>{{ value }}</a>
         </li>
     </ul>
   </div>

  <div ng-view=""></div>
```

main.html:

```
<p>Select from the list.</p>
```

content.html:

```
//loads the selected item from the list on index page
<h3>Selected: {{ message }}</h3>
```

```js
angular
  .module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .when('/content', {
         controller: 'ContentCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'views/content.html'

      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  })

.factory('myService', function($http, $rootScope){      
        var sharedService ={};
        sharedService.message = '';

        sharedService.prepforBroadcast = function(value){
            this.message = value;
            this.broadcastItem();
        };

        sharedService.broadcastItem = function(){
            $rootScope.$broadcast ('handleBroadcast');
        };

        return {
            sharedService: sharedService    
         };
})

  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, myService) {
    $scope.msg = data; //this will be json data 
    $scope.selectedValue;

    $scope.setSelectedValue = function(value){
        $scope.selectedValue = value;
        myService.sharedService.prepforBroadcast(value);

    }
  })

.controller('ContentCtrl', function ($scope, myService) {
    $scope.$on('handleBroadcast', function(){
        $scope.message = myService.sharedService.message;
    })
});
```

Not sure what exactly is the reason for not binding the data on the very first click even though when the template loads instantly. Any help or thought would be greatly appreciated. Scratching my head for a while.

Comment: probably thats beause ` ng-click="setSelectedValue(value)"`

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul ng-repeat="value in msg" ng-click="setSelectedValue(value)">
```

check with out `ng-click="setSelectedValue(value)"` part. seems like ur click is going to handle by `setSelectedValue(value)` function

Comment: Without ng-click, the selected value from the list won't even get broadcasted to the service.

Comment: On the first click, content.html loads fine, but in the `ContentCtrl` it never gets inside `$scope.$on` but reads everything outside of `$scope.$on`. Only on the second click and onwards, it gets inside `$scope.$on`. So, couldn't figure out why it's functioning like that.

Answer (score 0):

The `ng-repeat` and `ng-click` should be on li.

```
 <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="value in msg" ng-click="setSelectedValue(value)">
       <a href='#/content'>{{ value }}</a>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Tried that, does not make any difference at all.